# Camera reports database online to look it up?

Tags: database, aerial-photography, photos

I received tons of aerial photos that go back to 1930's and I have the information about the camera number and lens number and focal length. They were taken in a picture of the roll that tells us what it is.  What I would like to know is what they are and what project they were flown in and I want to get more information about them.

I was wondering if there is a camera calibration report database that I could look up online. Can anyone point me to where or who does that?